# Silverlight web application - access Resources (resx) from Web part

Tags: silverlight, wcf, resources, resx

I would like to access the resource file (Labels.resx) wich is stored in the Silverlight part of app from the web part. How can I do this?

The main idea is to access the localized labels stored in the Silverlight part and serve them as a wcf service. I know i can use the ResXResourceReader which allows to read the resx files directly but I would like to know if there is any way around.

thanks

Comment: Why do you need these resources? I would use javascript, it is the simplest way.

Comment: I need the resources for localized labels in telerik reporting.

Comment: If you need to localize labels of a ASP.Net web application, you can create resx file in asp.net project.